# Working with Dynamic User Controls

Tags: javascript, asp.net, user-controls

I have a custom user control containing information about a person that I am programmatically adding to the page.  To make things simple, lets say that my user control only holds the first and last name of a person.

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <asp:Label ID="lblFirstName" runat="server">First Name</asp:Label>
    </td>
    <td>
      <asp:TextBox ID="txtFirstName" runat="server" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
        <asp:Label ID="lblLastName" runat="server">Last Name</asp:Label>
    </td>
    <td>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtLastName" runat="server" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I need to allow the user to add people attending an event, and they need to be able to add as many people as possible.   I have an 'Add Person' button on screen, so when the user selects that button, a blank user control is added to the page for them to fill out. In the code behind, I keep track of how many people are attending so that I can render the user controls on postback by using this list.

```
public List<Person> AttendingPeople
{
    get { return ViewState["AttendingPeople"] == null ? new List<Person>() : ViewState["AttendingPeople"] as List<Person>; }
    set { ViewState["AttendingPeople"] = value; }
}
```

After filling out the information for all the people attending, the user needs to save the information.  When they select save, I need to validate that all of the textboxes were filled out.  I would prefer to do this with javascript, however, I don't know how to locate the information, since I can't tell for sure how many user controls are loaded on the page.  So far this is what I have.

```
function ValidateSave() {
    if ('<%= this.AttendingPeople.Count %>' == 0) {
        alert('Need to fill out at least one person whose attending.');
    }
    else {
        //Where user controls are added.
        var children = document.getElementById('<%= divAttending.ClientID %>').children;  
        for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {

            //Find table inside user control that holds data
            if (children[i].tagName == 'TABLE') {
                var table = children[i];
                var rows = table.rows;
                for (var r = 0; r < rows.length; r++) {
                    var row = rows[r];
                    //Not sure how to extract data from each row
                }
            }   
        }
    }
}
```

My first problem is that `'<%= this.AttendingPeople.Count %>'` always returns whatever the initial count was in the list.  In Page_Load, if I add 3 people to the list, then the count will always be 3.  If I don't add anything then the count will always be 0 regardless how many people I add over time.

Secondly, I seriously doubt that I am going about finding all of the data the right way.  I will appreciate any kind of advice or criticism.  I don't know much about ASP.NET, so I know I have a lot to learn.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
<%= this.AttendingPeople.Count %>
```

This code only prints the initial count of attending people once the view gets rendered. You can just check that in your page source.

To get the real count of attending people, you can store the initial value and increase or decrease it each time you add or remove a person. Something like that:

```
var apcount = '<%= this.AttendingPeople.Count %>';

/* do it when you add a person */
apcount++;
```